# javafx how to populate an listview with sql query result?

Tags: java, arrays, listview, javafx

I am new in java programming, so I wanna execute oracle sql statement and i wanna show the results in a listview , I'll put here the sql statemnt code,

I ve declared my list in other class...how shoult I call the list for putting the results.

thank a lot

public class ControllerBD {

```
public ControllerBD(){

}

public void Execute(){



    String dbUrl = "jdbc:odbc:test";
    String user = "SYSTEM";
    String password = "hpf101";
    try{
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();    
        System.out.println("Eroare incarcare driver!\n" + e);
    }
    try{
        Connection c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", user, password);
        Statement s= c.createStatement();
        ResultSet  r =
            s.executeQuery(
                " SELECT titlu FROM carti");


        while (r.next()) {
            System.out.println (
                r.getString ("titlu"));



        }
        s.close();
    } 
    catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

            }
}

            public void getvalues (){

            }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create your listview you can create method in that listview, that add data to list.
Then create instance of your listview in `Execute` class and then add data to this instance in `while (r.next()) {` cycle like this:

#### Example

```
while (r.next()) {
  listviewInstance.addData(r.getString ("titlu")));
}
```

All variable names and method names is example, you need to create yours.